# ASP.NET MVC data annotations with partial class doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

I have applied some validation with data annotations but somehow I am missing something in the code.

```
public class Person 
{
    public people SinglePerson { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ColorNames { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> WebCustomer { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PreviouslyOredered { get; set; }
}
```

and here is my  cs class

```
[MetadataType(typeof(peopleMetaData))]
public partial class people
{
}

public class peopleMetaData
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a name")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 2)]
    public string firstName { get; set; }
}
```

The `People` class has a `firstName` property that I want to do some validation to.

What am I missing?

Comment: did you apply the check for model in the controller ??

Comment: Hi, what check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For client side validation, make sure you have included 
`@section Scripts {     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") }` 
within your view

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @laz no worries :)

Answer (score 2):

In the metadata class, you must not specify your "properties" as full properties - just the type and name is needed - try this:

```
public class peopleMetaData
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a name")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 2)]
    public string firstName;
}
```

See - no `{ get; set; }` for the `firstName` "property" here

Comment: My solution now woks with {get;set;} specified. Is it better to leave it from the solution for some kind of code readability?

Comment: @laz: so what did you do / change to make it work now??

Comment: i added the "jqueryval" to the layout page (as suggested by @OrElse) and i used the "Model.IsValid" in the controller (as suggested by @moath naj)

Answer (score 1):

Partial classes can only exist within one project.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488(v=vs.100).aspx

*More specifically,*

> All partial-type definitions meant to be parts of the same type must
>   be defined in the same assembly and the same module (.exe or .dll
>   file). Partial definitions cannot span multiple modules.

Answer (score 0):

you have to check if the model is valid or not in the controller

```
if (ModelState.IsValid) {
  //do something 
}
else
{
return View();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the catch. It work's now but I don't get the validation message to be displayed.

Comment: you are welcome if you can mark answer as correct to avoid other answers

Answer (score 0):

You people Class doesn't have a property of `firstName`. 
You need that in your people class first, then the MetadataTypeClass

```
[MetadataType(typeof(peopleMetaData))]
public partial class people
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: the "people " is auto generated. I have a SQL table with that name that I have imported in with LINQ to SQL layer.